# Is it possible to describe a subtype of some primitive type?

Tags: c++, types, primitive

Consider the `double` primitive type. Let we declare function as the following:

```
void foo(double);
```

Is it possible to describe a user-defined type which can be passed to `foo` as parameter?

Comment: The question would have a different answer if we also had `void bar(double&);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course, though not through *actual* inheritance but by simulating it with an implicit conversion:

```
#include <iostream>

struct MoreDouble
{
   operator double() { return 42.5; }
};

void foo(double x)
{
   std::cout << x << '\n';
}

int main()
{
   MoreDouble md;
   foo(md);
}

// Output: 42.5
```

([Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7629987a08b7b4d5))

Whether this is a good idea is another question. I dislike implicit conversions in general so make sure you really need this before using it.

Comment: Can you get a refenrence to the standard which describes this conversion?

Comment: @St.Antario Please see 12.2.3 clause.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do so, if there is a user defines cast operator to your type.

```
void x(double){}

class A
{
    public:
    operator double(){return 0;}
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    x(a);
    return 0;
}
```